# How to identify if two List<string> are equal regardless of the order?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following 2 objects

```
List<string> list1
List<string> list2
```

On list 1 I have 3 items
On list 2 I have the same 3 items in a different order.

I need a simple method to return that both lists are equal when they contain the same elements regardless of order

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `SequenceEqual` with additional order:

```
return list1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `All` and `Contains` method like this, this will return true if both lists contains same elements even if the order is different:

```
bool control = list1.All(x => list2.Contains(x) && 
                          list1.Count(a => a == x) == list2.Count(b => b == x));
```

Comment: `SequenceEqual` requires items to be in the same order.

Comment: ah sorry I didn't see that different order part

Comment: `Contains` will return `true` if you have the same item in both list, but different number of times.

Comment: then we use  `list1.Count == list2.Count`

Comment: try comparing `{ "1", "2", "2"}` and `{"1", "1", "2"}` now ;)

Comment: Well, I don't think it's about me being happy, but yes, your solution should return correct results now. Complexity could be better, but yeah, results are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
bool equals = list1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(y => y));
```

I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should **consider using a HashSet**, rather than a List. Its a little less expensive:

```
HashSet<string> firstSet = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> secondSet = new HashSet<string>();

PopulateSets(firstSet, secondSet); //Example of method you might use to populate your hashsets.

bool isEqual = firstSet.SetEquals(secondSet);
```

**From MSDN:**

> The SetEquals method ignores duplicate entries and the order of elements in the other parameter.

Comment: what if something appeared more than once in the list?

Comment: Adding `firstSet` to `HashSet<string>` means you lost information about how many times particular string existed in source collection.

Comment: In your example `["a", "a", "b"]` to `["a", "b"]` Which mean that your solution considers only the equality of the unique items, base on the default equality comparer of the type.

Comment: Can you link to more info on `PopulateSets`?

Comment: PopulateSets is trivial; It serves to illustrate that you'll need two hashsets, with data in them, in order to do a comparison.